# check if a property is ignored by EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.3

Using EntityFramework 4.3 w/POCOs.
how can I check if a property on a model is ignored or not.

In my DBContext Class Hierarchy I am ignoring a property by

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EClass>().Ignore (f => f.IgnoredProperty());
```

In my BaseContext class, I need to check if that property is ignored or not.

```
private void ProcessGlobalConvention(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder, IGlobalConvention convention)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<typeof(this.GetType())>("Ignored Property");
}
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the EF power tools http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/10/ef-power-tools-beta4 to view your model. Is the property there?

Create a database. Is the column there?

Look at the Database.LogSqlEvents http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/08/ef6-sql-logging-part-1-simple-logging/ and parse the sql to see if the field name appears...

....unless you *really* want a code solution...?

IN WHICH CASE

New up your DbContext
Create one record and add it to the relevant DbSet
Get the DbEntityEntry
Look in CurrentValues.PropertyNames. Is your property there?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateDatabase()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<HomesContext>());

        var db = new HomesContext();

        Assert.IsFalse(db.Homes.Any());

        var home = db.Homes.Create();

        db.Homes.Add(home);

        var entry = db.Entry(home);

        Assert.IsTrue(entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.Contains("MaxResidents"));
        Assert.IsTrue(entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.Contains("MaxStaff"));
        Assert.IsFalse(entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.Contains("CurrentResidents"));
        Assert.IsFalse(entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.Contains("CurrentStaff"));

    }
public class HomesContext:DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Home>().Ignore(x => x.CurrentResidents);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    public DbSet<Home> Homes { get; set; }
}

public class Home
{
    public int HomeId { get; set; }
    public string HomeName { get; set; }

    public int MaxResidents { get; set; }
    public int MaxStaff { get; set; }

    public int CurrentResidents { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int CurrentStaff { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I needed a code solution. I can find out [NotMapped] properties but when you use the ModelBuilder to ignore a column, I cannot detect that.